# Django csrf_token forbidden on reload

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am new to python and django. I started an online app with user login etc. Everything works as expected. But if I am at a page with the related view having `@login_required` decorator and I reload the page I get the `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`. Just by reloading. All of my forms work perfectly as well. Can you tell me how can I fix this?
**A view:**

```
@login_required
def main(request):
    user=request.user
    if request.method=='POST':
        projectid=request.POST['project']
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=int(projectid))
        if project:
            change=Change(user=user, project=project,starttime=datetime.now())
            change.save()
            return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/timer.html', {'change':change}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            HttpResponse("Choose a valid project!")
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
        <span style="color:red">You have uncommitted changes:</span><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b><u>Project</u></b></td>
                    <td><b><u>Started</u></b></td>
                    <td><b><u>Finished</u></b></td>
                </tr>
                {%for f in unfinished_forms%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{form}}<td>
                </tr>
                {%endfor%}
            </table>
        </div>
        {%endif%}
        <div>
            <form action="/main/" method="post" name="project_list">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {%for p in project_list%}
                    <input type="radio" name="project" value="{{p.id}}">{{p.title}}<br>
                {%endfor%}
                <input type="submit" value="Start working!">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the view and template code for one of the situations you're referring to?

Comment: You might have used expired session at first attempt

Comment: I haven't touched sessions so far. Maybe this is the issue.